# GLFW Joystick controls

Tags: c++, glfw

I'm using GLFW to use joystick control as a possible input. I looked on their page about input handling(http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__input.html) and I only managed to get the name, button count and axes count of the joystick. I'm wondering how you could actually read in input from it, as there seems to be no function for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a closer look at `glfwGetJoystickAxes(int joy, int *count)` and `glfwGetJoystickButtons(int joy, int *count)` : both return a pointer to the state of the joystick's axes (resp. buttons) ;)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that it returned anything!